# cordova app why can I play my media on ios but fail on android?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

these are my codes. I can successfully play it on ios emulator but I cannot play it on my android. What's the problem?

```
game.PlayAudio("sound/eat.wav");

game.PlayAudio = function(src) {
var audio = new Media(src);
audio.play();
};
```

Comment: Have you ensured the file is being 'copied' onto the android platform? Also have you tried different audio formats - such as mp3?

Comment: @StevenAnderson I tried mp3 and wav, and they are copied to android's assets folder. But it still works on ios but not on android

Comment: Ok so other things to check... volume is definitely up/speakers on? Try remote debugging the app via chrome and a) check for console errors b) input your code via the console during a remote debugging session. 

Nothing else obvious is standing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@StevenAnderson

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

    if (device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") {

        eatSound = "/android_asset/www/sound/eat.wav";
        dieSound = "/android_asset/www/sound/die.wav";
        bossSound = "/android_asset/www/sound/boss.wav";
        shootSound = "/android_asset/www/sound/shoot.wav";

    }

    else {

        eatSound = "sound/eat.wav";
        dieSound = "sound/die.wav";
        bossSound = "sound/boss.wav";
        shootSound = "sound/shoot.wav";

    }

}, false);
```

I changed my code to this and it worked. The path on android devices is different. Thank you for your help!